# How can I create a proxy when the class having only one private constructor?

Tags: java, proxy, byte-buddy

Using ByteBuddy, I'd like to create a proxy for a class which has a private  constructor. That's the class:

```
public class Foo {

    private Foo() {
    }
}
```

I tried write some code like this but not work?

```
public class CreateAndExecuteProxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Constructor<?> superConstructor = Foo.class.getDeclaredConstructor();

        Class<? extends Foo> proxyType = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass( Foo.class, ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS )
                .defineConstructor( Visibility.PUBLIC )
                .intercept( MethodCall.invoke( superConstructor ).onSuper() )
                .make()
                .load( CreateAndExecuteProxy.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
                .getLoaded();

        Foo foo = proxyType.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing really you can do with Java byte code which does not permit calling a private constructor. There are two options you have:

1. Use `ByteBuddy::redefine` to add another constructor and either use an agent or premature loading to force this class into your class loader.
2. Use a library like *Objenesis* to create an instance without calling a constructor.